# Can I get a list of Locale-related values for android.location.Address getLocality()?

Tags: android, location, locale, android-resources

I need to check the name of some Spanish locations according to android.location.Address to know if the backend of my app will be able to process them out-of-the-box or if some work is going to be needed.

In Spain there are 4 official languages (Spanish, Galician, Basque, Catalan) and locations belonging to the regions of the later three may have names in both Spanish and their regional language, so I need to make sure what I'll be getting if I use Address to get the locations names.

Is there some site where I can check this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is one of the elements in the array returned by google geocoding API (which, I assume, is the one used by android.location classes).

```
{
           "long_name" : "Rúa da Batundeira",
           "short_name" : "Rúa da Batundeira",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Orense",
           "short_name" : "Orense",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Ourense",
           "short_name" : "Ourense",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Galicia",
           "short_name" : "GA",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "España",
           "short_name" : "ES",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "32960",
           "short_name" : "32960",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
```

Please, notice that "locality" here is "Orense" (Spanish name) and "administrative_area_level_2" is "Ourense" (Galician name for the same place).

Is there a way where I can check a full list instead of processing every locality through google geocoding API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I typed them all and wrapped them in this class & resources files https://github.com/alberovalley/GeografiaSpain The class has methods that return arrays of Strings with the data as you need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the names in all languages you can, regardless the default locale, force a certain language with this code:

```
        String language = "es"; // or the language you want to set

        // creating locale
        Locale locale = new Locale(language); 
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;

        // updating locale
        getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);

        //then you get the string you want normally
        String string = getResources().getString(R.string.whatever);
```

Take into consideration that after that everything in that activity will be requested to the that language, you will need to revert it back to the default one if you want to keep going normally.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thing is, the server to which my app sends the requests has a list of localities, and those with names both in Spanish and regional are in regional language. So, if my app gets a Spanish name and sends it on the request, the server will not recognise it. The client is open to change that, but to that end we need the list of names google is using.